# Cannot connect to my garry's mod server

Tags: hosting, garrys-mod

My server was working fine earlier, had a couple of mods on it, and then I just couldn't connect to it. I was connecting to it by typing "connect :27015" in console. This is what it say when I run the start.bat.

```
Console initialized.
ConVarRef mat_dxlevel doesn't point to an existing ConVar
Game.dll loaded for "Garry's Mod"
Initializing Steam libraries for Workshop..
Fetching Workshop Addons.. No -authkey
Adding Filesystem Addon 'd:\gmod\garrysmod\addons\curvypine's extra cw2.0 pack'
Adding Filesystem Addon 'd:\gmod\garrysmod\addons\customizable weaponry 2.0'
Adding Filesystem Addon 'd:\gmod\garrysmod\addons\cwextra hk416'
Adding Filesystem Addon 'd:\gmod\garrysmod\addons\falcos-prop-protection-master'

Adding Filesystem Addon 'd:\gmod\garrysmod\addons\garry's bombs 5 base'
Adding Filesystem Addon 'd:\gmod\garrysmod\addons\garry's bombs 5 materials'
Adding Filesystem Addon 'd:\gmod\garrysmod\addons\garry's fireworks 2 (final edi
tion)'
Adding Filesystem Addon 'd:\gmod\garrysmod\addons\ulib'
Adding Filesystem Addon 'd:\gmod\garrysmod\addons\ulx'
Adding Filesystem Addon 'd:\gmod\garrysmod\addons\urs'
Adding Filesystem Addon 'd:\gmod\garrysmod\addons\wac aircraft'
Adding Filesystem Addon 'd:\gmod\garrysmod\addons\wiremod'
Unknown command "authkey"
WARNING: Port 27015 was unavailable - bound to port 27016 instead
WARNING: Port 27005 was unavailable - bound to port 27006 instead
WARNING: Port 27020 was unavailable - bound to port 27021 instead
Network: IP (Omitted), mode MP, dedicated Yes, ports 27016 SV / 27006 CL
Error loading cfg/trusted_keys_base.txt
Error loading cfg/pure_server_minimal.txt
PREP OK
///////////////////////////////
//      Ulysses Library      //
///////////////////////////////
// Loading...                //
//  shared/defines.lua       //
//  shared/misc.lua          //
//  shared/util.lua          //
//  shared/hook.lua          //
//  shared/table.lua         //
//  shared/player.lua        //
//  server/player.lua        //
//  shared/messages.lua      //
//  shared/commands.lua      //
//  server/concommand.lua    //
//  server/util.lua          //
//  shared/sh_ucl.lua        //
//  server/ucl.lua           //
//  server/phys.lua          //
//  server/player_ext.lua    //
//  server/entity_ext.lua    //
//  shared/plugin.lua        //
//  shared/cami_global.lua   //
//  shared/cami_ulib.lua     //
// Load Complete!            //
///////////////////////////////
[ULIB] Loading SHARED module: ulx_init.lua
///////////////////////////////
//       ULX Admin Mod       //
///////////////////////////////
// Loading...                //
//  sh_defines.lua           //
//  lib.lua                  //
//  base.lua                 //
//  sh_base.lua              //
//  log.lua                  //
//  MODULE: slots.lua        //
//  MODULE: urs_server.lua   //
//  MODULE: uteam.lua        //
//  MODULE: votemap.lua      //
//  MODULE: xgui_server.lua  //
///////////////////////////////
// ULX GUI -- by Stickly Man //
///////////////////////////////
// Adding Main Modules..     //
//  bans.lua                 //
//  commands.lua             //
//  groups.lua               //
//  maps.lua                 //
//  settings.lua             //
// Adding Setting Modules..  //
//  cl_urs_gui.lua           //
//  client.lua               //
//  server.lua               //
// Adding Gamemode Modules.. //
//  sandbox.lua              //
// Loading Server Modules..  //
//  sv_bans.lua              //
//  sv_groups.lua            //
//  sv_maps.lua              //
//  sv_sandbox.lua           //
//  sv_settings.lua          //
//  sv_urs_gui.lua           //
// XGUI modules added!       //
///////////////////////////////
//  MODULE: chat.lua         //
//  MODULE: fun.lua          //
//  MODULE: menus.lua        //
//  MODULE: rcon.lua         //
//  MODULE: teleport.lua     //
//  MODULE: urs_cmds.lua     //
//  MODULE: user.lua         //
//  MODULE: userhelp.lua     //
//  MODULE: util.lua         //
//  MODULE: vote.lua         //
//  end.lua                  //
// Load Complete!            //
///////////////////////////////
Wiremod Version 'Unknown' loaded
 +---------------------------------+
 |          E2 EXTENSIONS          |
 +----------------+----------------+
 |    ENABLED     |    DISABLED    |
 +----------------+----------------+
 | console        | constraintcore |
 | file           | effects        |
 | find           | http           |
 | holo           | propcore       |
 | npc            | remoteupload   |
 | ranger         | wiring         |
 | serialization  |                |
 | sound          |                |
 +----------------+----------------+
KeyValues Error: RecursiveLoadFromBuffer:  got } in key in file In
AddonInfo,
KeyValues Error: RecursiveLoadFromBuffer:  got } in key in file In
AddonInfo,
HTTP failed - ISteamHTTP isn't available!
Executing dedicated server config file server.cfg
Using map cycle file cfg/mapcycle.txt.
Attempted to create unknown entity type lua_area!
Can't init lua_area
Attempted to create unknown entity type lua_area!
Can't init lua_area
Attempted to create unknown entity type lua_area!
Can't init lua_area
Attempted to create unknown entity type lua_area!
Can't init lua_area
Attempted to create unknown entity type lua_area!
Can't init lua_area
Attempted to create unknown entity type lua_area!
Can't init lua_area
Attempted to create unknown entity type lua_area!
Can't init lua_area
Attempted to create unknown entity type lua_area!
Can't init lua_area
Attempted to create unknown entity type lua_area!
Can't init lua_area

|------------------------|
|  Garry's Fireworks 2   |
|      Version 1         |
| Type !gworks2 for help |
|------------------------|

|Gbombs 5 physics module initializednot
|If you don't want this, delete the gb5_physics.lua file
Nav File is wrong or something (1)
Initializing Steam libraries for secure Internet server
Logging into Steam game server account
Usage: sv_setsteamaccount <login_token>
Writing cfg/banned_user.cfg.
Connection to Steam servers successful.
   Public IP is (Omitted).
Assigned persistent gameserver Steam ID [G-1:324466].
VAC secure mode is activated.
```

Here is my start.bat if it helps

```
@echo off
cls
echo Protecting srcds from crashes...
echo If you want to close srcds and this script, close the srcds window and type Y depending on your language followed by Enter.
title srcds.com Watchdog
:srcds
echo (%time%) srcds started.
start /wait srcds.exe -console -game garrysmod +map gm_genesis_b24 +maxplayers 24 +authkey (Omitted) +host_workshop_collection 660332050 +sv_setsteamaccount (Omitted)
echo (%time%) WARNING: srcds closed or crashed, restarting.
goto srcds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your port 27015 is already taken.

Restart your computer and it should work fine.

```
WARNING: Port 27015 was unavailable - bound to port 27016 instead
WARNING: Port 27005 was unavailable - bound to port 27006 instead
WARNING: Port 27020 was unavailable - bound to port 27021 instead
```